# How to add superscript to a complex axis label in R

Tags: r

I have a complex axis label I want to add to a graph in R. It includes superscript and subscript, however, one element of superscript keeps attaching itself to the wrong word in the label. The label should read: `umol[tracer]^-1`, `mmol[sponge]^-1`, `incubation^-1`. The superscript `-1` which comes after `[sponge]` keeps attaching itself to the `mmol` part, but it should be after the subscript `[sponge]`. Any help?

FYI the reason I use a text grob in my code below is because I have a primary axis title and a secondary axis title. I am very new to R!

```
grid.arrange(DC, left=textGrob(expression(paste(mu,"mol C or N "["tracer"]," mmol "["sponge"]^-1," incubation "^-1)), x=2.2, rot=90, hjust=0.38, gp=gpar(fontsize=12)))
```

This is the output I get, but I want to move the ^-1 to behind the word sponge:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ActPa.png)

UPDATE:

This is the code for my graph, using the data set iris as an example:

BN <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Sepal.Length))  + 
    geom_line(position=pd, size=1) + geom_point(position=pd, size=3, shape=21,    fill="white") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:8*1, limits=c(0,8)) + theme_bw() + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 18),legend.position="none", panel.border = element_rect(color="black", fill=NA, size=1), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=14), axis.title.x=element_text(margin = unit(c(3,0,0,0), "mm")), axis.title.y=element_blank(), legend.title=element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=14)) + scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "black"))

Using new code from Zhiqiang:
b <- grid.arrange(BN, left=textGrob(expression(paste(mu,"mol C or N "["tracer"]," mmol "["sponge"^"-1"]," incubation "^-1)), x=0.5, rot=90, hjust=0.38, gp=gpar(fontsize=10)))

With the new code, the -1 is in the correct place but is too small. 
[updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzQ0D.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted? It would be helpful if you could provide the data.

```
grid.arrange(DC, left=textGrob(expression(paste(mu,"mol C or N "["tracer"]," mmol "["sponge"^"-1"]," incubation "^-1)), x=2.2, rot=90, hjust=0.38, gp=gpar(fontsize=12)))
```

EDIT: Adding some space in front of `-1` can move it after `sponge`:

```
grid.arrange(DC, left=textGrob(expression(paste(mu,"mol C or N "["tracer"]," mmol "["sponge"]^"          -1"," incubation "^-1)), x=2.2, rot=90, hjust=0.38, gp=gpar(fontsize=12)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and while it is a step better (the -1 is now in the correct position), the -1 is smaller than it should be, as it is a superscript of a subscript, and I would like to get a regular sized superscript.

Comment: I have edited my answer. My solution might be clumsy.